# Hermitian Matrices $AA^{*}=CC^{*}$,

Tags: matrices

Could any one help me proving or disproving this statement:

If $A,B,C$ are $n\times n$ invertible matrices, with $AA^{*}=CC^{*}$, and $B^{*}=B$, does it follow that 
$$ ABA^{*}=CBC^{*} $$

thanks in advance!

Comment: there are counterexamples with 2x2 matrices

Comment: What hypothesis should be there to have the statement true?

Comment: $AB=BA$ and $CB=BC$ for example. In general you must have very strong assumptions.

Comment: OK, and this could be if both $A$ and $C$ are Hermitian

Comment: could be, but in general won't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one counter example with $2\times 2$ matrices.

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \\ i & 1\end{pmatrix}\quad A^*=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i \\ -i & 1\end{pmatrix}\quad AA^*=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$

$C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i\sqrt{2} \\ i\sqrt{2} & 0\end{pmatrix}\quad C^*=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i\sqrt{2} \\ -i\sqrt{2} & 0\end{pmatrix}\quad CC^*=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Then we have

$ABA^*=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2i \\ -2i & 0\end{pmatrix}\quad CBC^*=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: simpler counterexample: $A=I$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, and the same $B$

Comment: @Exodd they all commute, it cannot be a counter example...

Comment: same B as yours